# Conversational dialogue data

Tags: dataset, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying out some ideas around the [Neural Conversational Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05869) and looking for some actual dialogue data as my training data to play around. But it seems such data is not easy to find on the Web, compared to text corpus or part-of-speech tagged data. Are there any public dialogue datasets out there that would be useful as the training data.

It possible, I'd like to use dialogue data in the context of banking, finance, or anything related, but any general dialogue data will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This website has dialog datasets which can be used to build a conversational model. The dialogue datasets are classified under 'human-human' data. https://breakend.github.io/DialogDatasets/